# Data frame dimension comparison. Error: the condition has length > 1

Tags: r

I keep getting this Error message.

> Error in if (dim(df1) == dim(df2)) { : the condition has length > 1

I understand why I am getting it but I don't know how to make this code chunk work. I know of the **for-loop** workaround but I'm not quite sure how to fix this code chunk using that. Any thoughts?

Any help is appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), z = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), z = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

# Check if the data frames have the same dimensions
if (dim(df1) == dim(df2)) {
  # If the dimensions are the same, do nothing
  print("The data frames have the same dimensions.")
} else if (dim(df1)[1] < dim(df2)[1]) {
  # If df1 has fewer rows than df2, remove the excess rows from df2
  df2 <- df2[1:dim(df1)[1], ]
  print("df2 has been trimmed to match df1 in row count.")
} else {
  # If df2 has fewer rows than df1, remove the excess rows from df1
  df1 <- df1[1:dim(df2)[1], ]
  print("df1 has been trimmed to match df2 in row count.")
}
```

Comment: you can try changing the first line of your loop to `if (all(dim(df1)) == all(dim(df2)))`
that should work

Comment: Also, it might be better to replace `dim(df)[1]` with `nrow(df)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of the code is only to match the number of rows between `df1` and `df2` then you just need to index the output of `dim(df1)` and `dim(df2)`, since the output of `dim(df1) == dim(df2)` will be a condition of length 2, which causes problems for the `if` statement that can only take conditions of length 1. The output of `dim(df1) == dim(df2)` will be of length 2 since you are comparing both the number of rows and the number of columns, each of which returns a logical value. So comparing only the first element of `dim(df1)` and `dim(df2)` will only compare the number of rows in the two data frames. The following would work:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), z = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c("a", "b", "c"), z = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

# Check if the data frames have the same dimensions
if (dim(df1)[1] == dim(df2)[1]) {
  # If the dimensions are the same, do nothing
  print("The data frames have the same dimensions.")
} else if (dim(df1)[1] < dim(df2)[1]) {
  # If df1 has fewer rows than df2, remove the excess rows from df2
  df2 <- df2[1:dim(df1)[1], ]
  print("df2 has been trimmed to match df1 in row count.")
} else {
  # If df2 has fewer rows than df1, remove the excess rows from df1
  df1 <- df1[1:dim(df2)[1], ]
  print("df1 has been trimmed to match df2 in row count.")
}
```

If however, you want to compare both the number of rows and columns, the code should be modified a bit. Also to make the code a bit more readable, you can use the `nrow()` function instead of `dim()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One more question. what does the [1] do in all of this? Also, how would one change the code to compare both numbers of rows and columns?

Comment: The `[1]` chooses the first element of whatever object it is put after. The functionality is called indexing. So in this case `dim(df1)` produces two values, i.e. the number of rows and the number of columns. By writing `dim(df1)[1]` we are only extracting the first number, i.e. the number of rows.

Comment: To compare both numbers of rows and columns we can do as @juan_bzt suggested and change the code to `if (all(dim(df1) == dim(df2)))`. This condition would only be true when both numbers of columns and rows are the same. However, you probably also want to add another `else if` to handle when the number of columns is different. I would let the additional `else if` handle the  discrepancy in rows and then let the `else` handle discrepancy in columns, e.g. `else if (dim(df1)[1] > dim(df2)[1]) {print("df1 has been trimmed to match df2 in row count.")} else {print("Different number of columns")}`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the assumption that the values in the "x" and "y" are common to both dataframes? e.g. value "1" in df1$x corresponds to "1" in df2$x. If this is the case, the issue with your approach (apart from the error you're getting), is that if your data get edited and/or sorted you could potentially lose matching records:

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), z = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c("a", "b", "c"), z = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
df1 <- df1[order(-df1$x),]

# Trim df1 to nrow(df2)
df1 <- df1[1:nrow(df2),]
df1
# x y z
# 4 4 d 4
# 3 3 c 3
# 2 2 b 2
```

As you can see, df1 now has values in "x" that aren't going the be in df2$x. A more flexible approach is to use `%in%` to drop the rows you don't want. Doing so also negates the need to check if `nrow()` is the same or different for each df. First, in the order you have in your example dataframes:

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = letters[1:4], z = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3], z = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

# Keep rows only if values in df1$x exist %in% df2$x
df1 <- df1[df1$x %in% df2$x,]
df1
#   x y z
# 1 1 a 1
# 2 2 b 2
# 3 3 c 3

# Keep rows only if values in df2$x exist %in% df1$x
df2 <- df2[df2$x %in% df1$x,]
df2
# x y     z
# 1 1 a  TRUE
# 2 2 b FALSE
# 3 3 c  TRUE
```

and now if one (or both) dataframes have been edited:

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), z = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c("a", "b", "c"), z = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
df1 <- df1[order(-df1$x),]

df1 <- df1[df1$x %in% df2$x,]
df1
# x y z
# 3 3 c 3
# 2 2 b 2
# 1 1 a 1

df2 <- df2[df2$x %in% df1$x,]
df2
# x y     z
# 1 1 a  TRUE
# 2 2 b FALSE
# 3 3 c  TRUE
```

So even though df1 remains in descending order by the "x" column, the records correspond to those in df2.

It doesn't matter which one you run first. Of course, you don't get a `print()` statement returned this way, but it's easy enough to 'eyeball' compare the before and after `nrow()` values. If you need to 'match' more than one column, for instance "x" AND "y", use something like:

```
df1 <- df1[paste(df1$x, df1$y) %in% paste(df2$x, df2$y),]
df2 <- df2[paste(df2$x, df2$y) %in% paste(df1$x, df1$y),]
```